# Cordova - check if "Automatic date and time checkbox" in Settings is checked

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there a way to access the 'Automatic date and time' setting (and other settings maybe?) with Cordova?
My point is to do some action, when my app is launching and when it detect that the automatic date setting on the device is turned off.

For now Im looking for an Android solution, but the iOS would be nice too.